# How to attach multiple html files in Email body from unix

Tags: unix, awk, smtp, html-email

I am trying to generate and send html files by attaching to email body. I tried using awk for generating and sending one file. eg. the input file MARTINI has these records:

```
1554894,2015-04-16,00:21:52,processes.martini_gsicorptradeeventoutput.instancecount,0,1,UP
1554793,2015-04-15,22:03:52,processes.martini_gsicorptradeeventoutput.instancecount,2,0,DOWN
```

and I have this awk in a file named HTML:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=","
    print  "MIME-Version: 1.0"
    print  "To:lijo@abc.com"
    print  "From:lijo@abc.com"
    print  "Subject: Health check"
    print  "Content-Type: text/html"
    print  "Content-Disposition: inline"
    print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1"><TH>Ref_id</TH><TH>EOD</TH><TH>Time</TH><TH>Process</TH><TH>Desc</TH><TH>Instance</TH><TH>Status</TH>"
    }
    {
    printf "`<TR>`"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    printf "`<TD>%s</TD>`", $i
    print "`</TR>`"
    }
END {
    print "`</TABLE></BODY></HTML>`"
} ' /home/martini > /home/martini_html
```

Later I send this file through email `cat MARTINI_HTML | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t` . This works until here. But now i have 2 new tasks
How to convert multiple files Say MARTINI1, MARTINI2 ... etc into html files and how to attach them in email body as separate table block and not as a single table. Assuming two files are attached then email body should look similar to the image attached. [image: Email_Body]

Comment: Apart from the fact that html email are a questionable thing in general, why don't you use a decent mail utility like the `mailx` command? It allows to specify multiple attachments. And the chances that your messages are _not_ invalid html and look funny on most email clients are slightly higher...

Comment: Seems like some of the mail utilities are not available in this unix session. I tried `which mailx` and it returned `which: no mailx in ` multiple directories.

Comment: Often it is aliased as simply `mail`. It is the BSD mail client, sometimes also called "heirloom". You probably have to install it.

Comment: archive the html files (e.g., `tar -zcvf htmls.tar.gz input1.htm input2.htm` or `zip htmls.zip input1.htm input2.htm`) and attach the _archive_ to the email message.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:  cheat.

Send yourself an email with two attachments.  Use that raw email as a template.  That way you can skip all the discovery about MIME types and whatnot.